# php blocked words from mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, words, blocked

I need to save a list of blocked words in mysql database and use my below code to block some words or phone numbers... Please help with a little example. 
Thanks

```
$blocked_words=array("word1" ,"word2","word3");  
$string_words=explode(" ", $_POST['text']);  
$phone_words=explode(" ", $_POST['phone']);  
$result = array_intersect($blocked_words, $string_words);  
$result_phone = array_intersect($blocked_words, $phone_words);
```

Comment: What do you need help with? Your `array_intersect()` should pretty much work.

Comment: All the database extensions in the PHP manual have appropriate examples. What's your exact problem?

Comment: How you store it in database, what table structure looks like, what you expect as result, what have you tried so far? That's not hard task but be more specific please. Like Alvaro said, there are plenty of examples in PHP manual.

Comment: I want to fetch words from my database but not like this $blocked_words=array("word1" ,"word2","word3");

Comment: @Omer, your answer is still missing... how you store words in database? How your database table where you keep stored words looks like? We can just guess. How we can answer "how to fetch your database" if we dont know what's the structure of your database-table where you want to store or have stored blocked words.

Answer (score 2):

You can generate an array from the blocked_words table and use it like above code you mentioned,

Or
May be what you think you want is something similar to

```
"SELECT word FROM blocked_words WHERE word == $Phone_num"
```

and check whether row count is 0 or not for determining whether it is blocked word?

Comment: 1st: He cant use his code because there's no input-filter against $_POST data but fetching blocked_words into array is generally good idea + intersection of arrays. 2nd: running multiple queries like this one, seeking for single words one-by-one, for unknown number of words cant be that good.

Answer (score 0):

I think i was not able to explain, but i have completed my requirement from one of a stackoverflow answers from another post

here is what i was required

```
$blocked_words=array();
$q="select words from blocked";
$rs=mysql_query($q);
while($rd=mysql_fetch_object($rs))
{
$blocked_words[]=$rd->words;
}
```

by this i got all words from table 'blocked' into $blocked_words, now i can use it further

Thanks